# R command for stphtest in Stata

Tags: r, stata

What is the equivalent command in R for `stphtest` in Stata?

If there is not a 1-to-1 command, how do you test the assumption of proportional hazards in a Cox Proportional-Hazards Regression model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand Glen's answer:
I know how different a mindset R poses for Stata users. 
First run the coxph model:

```
model.coxph <- coxph(Surv(t1, t2, event) ~ var1 + var2, data = data)

> summary(model.coxph0)
                      coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)   
var1             1.665e-01  1.181e+00  1.605e-01  1.038  0.29948   
var2            -1.358e-03  9.986e-01  6.852e-04 -1.982  0.04746 *
```

Than run `cox.zph` on the model:

```
(viol.cox <- cox.zph(model.coxph0))

            rho chisq     p
var1     0.0486 1.095 0.295
var2    -0.0250 0.258 0.611
GLOBAL       NA 1.462 0.691
```

Each p value ought to be > 0.05 so that the assumptions are not violated.
You can also plot the scaled schoenfeld residuals with a simple `plot` on the cox.zph:

```
> plot(viol.cox)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Yuval! I'm not a STATA user, but the information I could find about testing the assumptions were done in STATA. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

See `?survival:::cox.zph`:

> Description
>
> Test the proportional hazards assumption for a Cox regression model fit (coxph).